# React authentication token issue

Tags: reactjs, api, authentication, axios

I am getting this message from response
**"Authentication credentials were not provided."** while I am hitting the api : *https://class.arenawebsecurity.net/user-authentication/api/user-class-time/18/*

I have implemented authentication key at three end point . One is working and this one is not working. I have used Axios. My code where I am getting error is:

```
        let videoResponseToken = {
            headers: {
                Authorization: 'Bearer ' + sessionStorage.getItem('profile_token') //the token is a variable which holds the token
            }
        }
        await axios.put(ApiUrl.BaseUrl + `user-authentication/api/user-class-time/${userId}/` , videoResponseToken)
            .then(function (response) {
                console.log("first function response >", response)
                // setStopVideo()
                if (response.status === 200 || response.status === 201 || response?.data?.class_time === true) {
                    loadVideo()
                }
                if (response?.data?.class_time === false) {
                    setVideoOver(true)
                    localStorage.setItem('videoStatus', response?.data?.class_time)
                    setTimeup('')
                }
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                if (error?.response?.data?.class_time === false)
                    setVideoOver(true)
                localStorage.setItem('videoStatus', error?.response?.data?.class_time)
            })
    }
    if (timeup === true) {
        console.log("I am going to fetch video link for you!");
        // setInterval(function checktimevalidation() { videoResponseFunc() }, 60000)
            videoResponseFunc()
    }
```

For better understanding I am giving the whole component snippet:

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { addMinutes, format, getMinutes, roundToNearestMinutes } from 'date-fns';
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import ApiUrl from './ApiUrl';
import CountDown from './CountDown';
import Header from './Header';
import { ToastContainer, toast } from 'react-toastify';
import 'react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css';

const Dashboard = () => {
    // let minutes = 0
    // console.log(getMinutes(new Date()) < 15 ? format(roundToNearestMinutes(new Date(), { nearestTo: 30, roundingMethod: 'ceil' }), 'p') : getMinutes(new Date()) > 15 && getMinutes(new Date()) < 21 ? format(roundToNearestMinutes(new Date(), { nearestTo: 15, roundingMethod: 'ceil' }), 'p') : getMinutes(new Date()) > 30 && getMinutes(new Date()) < 40 ? format(roundToNearestMinutes(new Date(), { nearestTo: 30, roundingMethod: 'ceil' }), 'p') : getMinutes(new Date()) > 39 && getMinutes(new Date()) < 45 ? format(roundToNearestMinutes(new Date(), { nearestTo: 30, roundingMethod: 'ceil' }), 'p') : getMinutes(new Date()) === 45 ? format(roundToNearestMinutes(new Date(), { nearestTo: 30, roundingMethod: 'ceil' }), 'p') : getMinutes(new Date()) > 59 || getMinutes(new Date())<1 ? format(addMinutes(new Date(),30), 'p') : getMinutes(new Date()) ===30 ? format(addMinutes(new Date(),30),'p') : format(roundToNearestMinutes(new Date(), { nearestTo: 30, roundingMethod: 'ceil' }), 'p'));
    // Fetching users information
    const [userData, setUserData] = useState({})
    // Getting users ID from local host
    const userId = localStorage.getItem("userId")

    /*============================================== 
    States for timing calculation starts from here 
    ================================================*/

    // Below state is helping to round the time to nearest 30
    // This is original code which is working
    // const [time, setTime] = useState(getMinutes(new Date()) < 15 ? (roundToNearestMinutes(new Date(), { nearestTo: 30, roundingMethod: 'ceil' })) : (roundToNearestMinutes(new Date(), { nearestTo: 15, roundingMethod: 'ceil' })))
    const [time, setTime] = useState(getMinutes(new Date()) < 15 ? (roundToNearestMinutes(new Date(), { nearestTo: 30, roundingMethod: 'ceil' })) : getMinutes(new Date()) > 15 && getMinutes(new Date()) < 21 ? (roundToNearestMinutes(new Date(), { nearestTo: 15, roundingMethod: 'ceil' })) : getMinutes(new Date()) > 30 && getMinutes(new Date()) < 40 ? (roundToNearestMinutes(new Date(), { nearestTo: 30, roundingMethod: 'ceil' })) : getMinutes(new Date()) > 39 && getMinutes(new Date()) < 45 ? (roundToNearestMinutes(new Date(), { nearestTo: 30, roundingMethod: 'ceil' })) : getMinutes(new Date()) === 45 ? (roundToNearestMinutes(new Date(), { nearestTo: 30, roundingMethod: 'ceil' })) : getMinutes(new Date()) > 59 || getMinutes(new Date()) < 1 ? (addMinutes(new Date(), 30)) : getMinutes(new Date()) === 30 ? (addMinutes(new Date(), 30)) : (roundToNearestMinutes(new Date(), { nearestTo: 30, roundingMethod: 'ceil' })))
    // Below state is setting user selected time from radio input
    const [selectedTime, setSelectedTime] = useState(new Date())
    console.log("selected time", selectedTime);
    // setting countdown end time from local storage after getting response
    const [timer, setTimer] = useState('') /* Initially timer is getting todays current time. If pass a string or empty field it shows NAN. If give new Date() set timeup true */
    console.log("I am timer", timer);
    // Below state is checking whether countdown is over or not
    const [timeup, setTimeup] = useState(false)
    console.log("Time up", timeup);
    // Setting video link from server response in below state
    const [video, setVideo] = useState('')
    // Checking whether video watching time is over or not in below state
    const [videoOver, setVideoOver] = useState(false)
    console.log("video over", videoOver);
    const [utctime, setUtcTime] = useState(localStorage.getItem('start_date'))


    // Fetching data of users from server
    useEffect(() => {
        let profileToken = {
            headers: {
                Authorization: 'Bearer ' + sessionStorage.getItem('profile_token')  //the token is a variable which holds the token
            }
        }
        axios.get(ApiUrl.BaseUrl + `user-authentication/api/profile/${userId}/`, profileToken)
            .then(function (response) {
                setUserData(response.data.data)
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
            })

    }, [])
    // ===========User data fetch complete ========================

    /* setInterval(async function videoResponseFunc() {
        await axios.put(ApiUrl.BaseUrl + `user-authentication/api/user-class-time/${userId}/`)
            .then(function (response) {
                console.log(response)
                setStopVideo()
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log("I am from video link error", error)
                if (error.response.data.class_time === false)
                setVideoOver(true)
            })
    }, 8000) */

    // This function is executing after selecting a specific time for countdown
    function timeSlot() {
        console.log("inside time slot function");
        const utcYear = new Date().getUTCFullYear();
        const utcMonth = new Date().getUTCMonth();
        const utcDay = new Date().getUTCDate();
        const utcHours = selectedTime.getUTCHours();
        const utcMinutes = selectedTime.getUTCMinutes();
        const utcSeconds = selectedTime.getUTCSeconds();

        let selectedTimeToken = {
            headers: {
                Authorization: 'Bearer ' + sessionStorage.getItem('profile_token')  //the token is a variable which holds the token
            }
        }
        axios.post(ApiUrl.BaseUrl + `user-authentication/api/user-select-time/`, {
            user_id: localStorage.getItem('userId'),
            video_start_date: `${utcYear}-${utcMonth + 1}-${utcDay}`,
            video_start_time: `${utcHours}:${utcMinutes}:${utcSeconds}`
        }, selectedTimeToken)
            .then(function (response) {
                console.log(response);
                localStorage.setItem("start_date", response.data.start_date_time)
                setTimer(localStorage.getItem('start_date'))
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
                toast.error("You have already claimed your free access!")
            });
    }
    // ======================= submit button first function end ====================


    async function loadVideo() {
        let videoToken = {
            headers: {
                Authorization: 'Bearer ' + sessionStorage.getItem('profile_token')  //the token is a variable which holds the token
            }
        }
        await axios.get(ApiUrl.BaseUrl + `user-authentication/api/class-video/`, videoToken)
            .then(function (response) {
                console.log("function two success response", response)
                if (response.status === 200 || response.status === 201) {
                    setVideo(response?.data?.data[0]?.class_video)
                    // localStorage.setItem('url', response.data.data[0].class_video)
                }
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
            })
    }

    async function videoResponseFunc() {
        let videoResponseToken = {
            headers: {
                Authorization: 'Bearer ' + sessionStorage.getItem('profile_token') //the token is a variable which holds the token
            }
        }
        await axios.put(ApiUrl.BaseUrl + `user-authentication/api/user-class-time/${userId}/` , videoResponseToken)
            .then(function (response) {
                console.log("first function response >", response)
                // setStopVideo()
                if (response.status === 200 || response.status === 201 || response?.data?.class_time === true) {
                    loadVideo()
                }
                if (response?.data?.class_time === false) {
                    setVideoOver(true)
                    localStorage.setItem('videoStatus', response?.data?.class_time)
                    setTimeup('')
                }
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                if (error?.response?.data?.class_time === false)
                    setVideoOver(true)
                localStorage.setItem('videoStatus', error?.response?.data?.class_time)
            })
    }
    if (timeup === true) {
        console.log("I am going to fetch video link for you!");
        // setInterval(function checktimevalidation() { videoResponseFunc() }, 60000)
            videoResponseFunc()
    }
    // videoResponseFunc()
    return (
        <div>
            <Header />
            <ToastContainer />
            <div className='text-center mt-10'>
                <div className={`${timeup ? 'hidden' : 'block'}`}> {/* className={`${timeup ? 'hidden' : 'block'}`} */}
                    <div> {/* className={`${startCountdown || localStorage.getItem('start_time') ? 'block' : 'hidden'}`} */}
                        <h1 className='text-lg font-semibold mb-5'>Video Will Start In</h1>
                        <CountDown timer={timer} setTimeup={setTimeup} time={utctime} />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className={`${timeup ? 'block' : 'hidden'} bg-slate-100 mx-24 rounded-lg mt-10`}> {/* ${timeup ? 'block' : 'hidden'} */}
                    <video key={video} width="90%" height="240" className='rounded-xl mx-auto py-10' autoPlay muted controls>
                        <source src={video && video} type="video/mp4" />
                    </video>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className='grid grid-cols-12 md:gap-12 md:mx-24 mt-16 mb-10'>
                <div className='col-span-12 md:col-span-5 bg-slate-100 mb-10 md:mb-0 rounded-lg p-10 flex flex-col items-center leading-loose'>
                    <h1 className='text-2xl font-bold'>Welcome {userData?.name}</h1>
                    <p>ID:#220014</p>
                    <p>{userData?.name}</p>
                    <p>Admission: <span className='text-red-500'>Pending</span></p>
                    <p className='text-center'>Course Title: Security & Ethical Hacking. Linux & Freelancing.</p>
                </div>
                <div className='bg-slate-100 col-span-12 md:col-span-7 rounded-lg grid grid-cols-2 p-10'>
                    <span className='font-bold'>Name:</span><span> {userData?.name}</span>
                    <span className='font-bold'>Email:</span><span> {userData?.email}</span>
                    <span className='font-bold'>Phone:</span><span> {userData?.phone_number}</span>
                    <span className='font-bold'>Nid:</span><span> {userData?.nid_passport_no}</span>
                    <span className='font-bold'>Birth Date:</span><span> {userData?.date_of_bath}</span>
                    <span className='font-bold'>Gender:</span><span> {userData?.gender}</span>
                    <span className='font-bold'>Institute:</span><span> {userData?.school_college}</span>
                    <span className='font-bold'>Address:</span><span> {userData?.present_address}</span>
                    <span className='font-bold'>City:</span><span> {userData?.city_name}</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            {/* ${startCountdown ? 'hidden': timeup ? 'hidden' : 'block'} */}
            <div className={`${timer || localStorage.getItem('start_date') ? 'hidden' : 'block'} my-24 bg-slate-100 md:mx-24 p-10 rounded-lg`}> {/* ${selectedTime > new Date() || localStorage.getItem('start_date') ? 'hidden' : timeup? 'hidden' : 'block'} */}
                <p className='md:text-center text-xl font-semibold opacity-90 mb-4'>Congratulations! You are now eligible for our free web security class. Select your time slote to view.</p>
                <div className='flex flex-col gap-3 md:ml-12'>
                    <div><input type="radio" name='time' className="mr-2" onBlur={() => setSelectedTime(time)} /><label htmlFor="">First session will start at <b>{format(new Date(time), 'p')}</b></label></div>
                    <div><input type="radio" name='time' className="mr-2" onBlur={() => setSelectedTime(addMinutes(time, 30))} /><label htmlFor="">Second session will start at <b>{format(addMinutes(time, 30), 'p')}</b></label></div>
                    <div><input type="radio" name='time' className="mr-2" onBlur={() => setSelectedTime(addMinutes(time, 60))} /><label htmlFor="">Last session will start at <b>{format(addMinutes(time, 60), 'p')}</b></label></div>
                    <button className='w-fit bg-[linear-gradient(90deg,#56b5e3,#7d58a5)] mx-auto px-5 py-2 text-white text-xl rounded mt-5 md:mt-0' onClick={() => timeSlot()}>Submit</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Dashboard;
```

**Thanks in advance!**

Comment: Did you read the error?

Comment: Yeah I read it . it is saying 
"Authentication credentials were not provided."

Comment: Please get in the habit of reading the error and making an attempt to understand it, don't ignore errors. The error is clearly telling you what's going on, which should lead you to the right debugging path. The error tells you you're not sending the token properly. You're sending `videoResponseToken` in the PUT body, not in the headers.

Comment: Andy Ray, I truly respect your suggestion but whenever I get an error I try to understand them. In this case I also can clearly understand that the server can not get the authentication key and I tried to solve it through axios documentation and googling but nothing helped. That's why I threw this question. Anyway I will keep your suggestion on my mind as it will help me to grow in my career. Have a nice day mate!